# Tkinter, как размещать обьекты на дочернем окне

Tags: python, tkinter

Здравствуйте, я создал кнопку которая создает новое окно

```
def infowindow():
    mGui1 = Tk()
    ment = StringVar()
    mGui1.geometry('250x250+500+300')
    mGui1.title('Info')
file_menu1.add_command(label='Contatti', command=infowindow)
```

Всё работает но я не могу понять как в нём что-то делать, к примеру вывести текст

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто при объявлении нового окна как в примере (это окно `windows`) добавляйте в значении расположения виджета окно в котором он должен быть размещен. 
В примере при открытии нажатии на кнопку `button_1` вызывается окно `windows`  где размещена кнопка `button`

```
from tkinter import *
def infowindow():
    windows = Toplevel()
    windows.title('открытое окно')
    windows.geometry('400x400')
    button = Button(windows, text='открыть окно', font='Times 12', command=infowindow)
    button.place(x=0, y=0)

mGui1 = Tk()
ment = StringVar()
mGui1.geometry('250x250+500+300')
mGui1.title('Info')
button_1 = Button(mGui1, text='открыть окно', font='Times 12', command=infowindow)
button_1.place(x=0, y=0)
mGui1.mainloop()
```