# Как размещать изображения на дочернем окне? Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Научился размещать изображения на главном окне в моей программе,
но теперь хочется узнать как можно разместить изображение на дочернем окне.

Весь код я поместил на файл-обменнике так-как код длинный.

**Вот пример кода:**

```
mGui = Tk()
ment = StringVar()
mGui.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", callback)


mGui.geometry('450x450+500+300')
mGui.title('R6S Operator Randomizer | Closed Beta 5.0')

w1 = Label(text='Copyright © 2018 JMax. All rights reserved').place(x = 212, 
y = 430, width = 250)

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Sledge.jpg"))
panel = Label(mGui, image = img)
panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "no")
```

**Вот дочернее окно:**

```
def wpronostico():
Child()

class Child(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(mGui)
        self.init_child()

    def scelta(self):
        tk.Label(self, text='' + random.choice(code_list3)).place(x = 87, y = 110)

    def init_child(self):
        self.title('Pronostico')
        self.geometry('200x200')
        tk.Button(self, text='Vincerai?', command=self.scelta).pack()
```

Весь [код](http://dropmefiles.com/jxgsN).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[*"Ссылку на изображение следует сохранять"*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767818/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-label-python3-tkinter/767829#comment1195447_767818) т.к. [по завершению выполнения функции, картинка удаляется в CPython, так как нет больше ссылок на неё](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767818/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-label-python3-tkinter/767829#comment1195558_767829) как прокоментировал [@jfs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/23044/jfs), по этому скорее всего у вас и не создавалось изображение на дочернем окне когда вы пытались его реализовать. Для этого надо сохранить переменную с изображение как показано на примере (т.е. называется `self.img`)

Пример если вам нужно только для дочерного окна изображение.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


class Main(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry('250x250+500+300')
        self.title('Info')
        button_1 = Button(self, text='открыть окно', font='Times 12',
                          command=self.started_create)
        button_1.place(x=0, y=0)

    def started_create(self):
        self.top_level = Top()


class Top(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title('открытое окно')
        self.geometry('400x400')
        self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Sledge.jpg"))
        self.panel = Label(self, image=self.img)
        self.panel.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand="no")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = Main()
    main.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

А этот пример предоставляет вам возможность использовать вам картинку как в главном окне так и в дочернем

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


class Main(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry('250x250+500+300')
        self.title('Info')
        self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Sledge.jpg"))
        self.panel_1 = Label(self, image=self.img)
        self.panel_1.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand="no")
        button_1 = Button(self, text='открыть окно', font='Times 12',
                          command=self.started_create)
        button_1.place(x=0, y=0)

    def started_create(self):
        self.top_level = Top()
        self.top_level.panel['image'] = self.img


class Top(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title('открытое окно')
        self.geometry('400x400')
        self.panel = Label(self)
        self.panel.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand="no")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = Main()
    main.mainloop()
```

или так по примеру вашего [предыдущего вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/766690/255866):

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


def info_window():
    windows = Toplevel()
    windows.title('открытое окно')
    windows.geometry('400x400')
    panel = Label(windows, image=img)
    panel.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand="no")
    button = Button(windows, text='открыть окно', font='Times 12', command=infowindow)
    button.place(x=0, y=0)


mGui1 = Tk()
mGui1.geometry('250x250+500+300')
mGui1.title('Info')
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Sledge.jpg"))
panel_main = Label(mGui1, image=img)
panel_main.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand="no")
button_1 = Button(mGui1, text='открыть окно', font='Times 12', command=info_window)
button_1.place(x=0, y=0)
mGui1.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]